# style.display="block" for event.target element and style.display="none" for other elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, event-handling, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I am trying to set the display property to "none" for all elements that has the "option" class, but then I want to extract the element I clicked on and change the display property from "none" back to "block".

I would like to find a solution in vanilla JS.

```
<h1 class="option" id="header1">Header 1</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header2">Header 2</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header3">Header 3</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header4">Header 4</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header5">Header 5</h1>

document.querySelector('*').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let clickedId = event.target.id;
    let clickedClass = event.target.className;

    if (clickedClass === "option") {
        var list = document.querySelectorAll(".option");        
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    list[i].style.display = "none";
            };

            document.getElementById(clickedId).style.display = "block";
    }

    console.log(event.target.style.display);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: if you hide the `<h1/>` list, how can you click on it (while it was hidden by `{display : none;}`) ? Have you ever think about it?

Comment: Your code works fine in latest Chrome(62) and Safari(11) on Mac at least. It may not be optimal, but it is functional.

Comment: Hey @Narcis, yeah I'm just starting out so I have a lot of room to improve, but I would be happy to see a more efficient way if you have any ideas?

Comment: Hey @Kai, there is no <h1> list, if you are talking about the list variable, that has been defined for use in the for loop.

Comment: I got your idea. So initially you have a list of `h1`, then you want to hide other if user click on one, right?

Comment: @Kai yeah, well it’s just a bunch of h1 tags, not a list of h1 tags. But the rest is correct 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, but does some unnecessary things like:

- the call to `document.querySelector('*')` when you already have the `document` object to which to attach events
- the call to `document.getElementById(clickedId)` when you already have the `event.target` to point to your clicked element
- setting the `display` style to `none` and then to `block` for your clicked element

Ideally, you should attach the `click` event to the closest parent of your elements, if possible. Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
let parent = document.querySelector("#all_options_parent") || document;

parent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.className === "option") {
        event.target.style.display = "block";

        let allOptions = parent.querySelectorAll(".option");

        for (let option of allOptions) {
            if (option != event.target) {
                option.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just ignore the one that was clicked.

```js
document.querySelector('*').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let clickedId = event.target.id;
    let clickedClass = event.target.className;

    if (clickedClass === "option") {
        var list = document.querySelectorAll(".option");        
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                    // ignore the one that was clicked
                    if (list[i] == event.target) continue

                    list[i].style.display = "none";
            };

            // document.getElementById(clickedId).style.display = "block";
    }

    // it is only useful if you display all the hidden again.
    event.target.style.display = "block";

    console.log(event.target.style.display);
});
```

```html
<h1 class="option" id="header1">Header 1</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header2">Header 2</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header3">Header 3</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header4">Header 4</h1>
<h1 class="option" id="header5">Header 5</h1>
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: it ignores the clicked one in for loop.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I will give this a shot and get back to you!

Comment: to me if may break another element has class 'option' also. In this case I prefer to do something like `jQuery.sibling()`

Comment: @RafaelQuintela you could put the explanation in your answer so that people don't have to dig through comments in future :)